# Android: Reading Bitwise Operator OR in View.setSystemUiVisibility(int)

Tags: java, android, view, bitwise-operators

In the 'Full Activity' template provided in Android Studio the following code is used:

```
// Note that some of these constants are new as of API 16 (Jelly Bean)
// and API 19 (KitKat). It is safe to use them, as they are inlined
// at compile-time and do nothing on earlier devices.

mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

I noticed that each of these flags have a certain final int value however what is the function of the | used along with these values?

Comment: It's a binary **addition**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They apply a bitwise OR operation to all the numbers, combining then into another number that contains all the the flags.

To make it more clear: let's say you have flags `View.FLAG_1 = 1`, `View.FLAG_2 = 2` and `View.FLAG_3 = 4`. The values of these flags in binary would be `001`, `010` and `100`.

If you pass `View.FLAG_1 | View.FLAG_3` to your method, you're passing `001 | 100`, which is equal to `101`. Your method will then understand these two flags were passed.

Comment: Oh so each combination whether it be more or less will result in a particular total value? So with your example `View.FLAG_1 | View.FLAG_3`, `View.FLAG_1 | View.FLAG_2`, `View.FLAG_1` would all result in a different total value?

So basically using `|` would make things easier for us by letting us not have to worry about what total value to pass in and instead we just need to worry about what flags we want to use? Behind the scene the method will simply handle the total binary value that came from the combination that was used as an argument?